# How can I recover a GPG private key from a PC which has died?

Tags: pgp, data-recovery

Long story short - PC with kleopatra processor died, and I only have a backup of my public key.

I've gone into the HDD and tried to re-jig kleopatra in the hope it would remember everything for me on another machine but that hasn't gone well...

Do I just need to get this HDD into a new PC and boot from it, then export my private key?

Comment: Solved - Documents and Settings\UserName\Application Data\gnupg

contains everything you need :)

Comment: This question is about applications files management, not about security. @cam: Thank for feedback anyway;-)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot recover from a public key to a private one – at least not within any kind of reasonable (computing) time. Being able to calculate a private key from the public one would circumvent encryption and would lead all efforts to ad absurdum.

You need to either:

- Try to recover from an old backup (like you succeeded to do following your comment)
- Revoke the key (on key servers) if you published it using a revocation certificate (you hopefully created). If you haven't, do so *now*.

There is no way to recover control over a lost private key – if there is no copy left, you've lost control over it.